# Uso de generators com while resulta em loop infinito

Tags: php, generators

fiz um pequeno exemplo de uso de generators para entender melhor seu funcionamento no php.

o método `getValues` é um exemplo de valores que viriam de um banco de dados ou qualquer outra fonte de dados que retorna um array.

usando o laço `while` com uma variável de "controle" chamada `$iterator` o resultado é um loop infinito, mas se eu usar o `foreach` funciona sem problemas, o que está errado?

```
<?php


$iterator = 0;

function getValues(&$iterator){

    while($iterator < 1) {
        $iterator++;
        yield ['valor1', 'valor2'];
    }
}

while($values = getValues($iterator)) {

    var_dump($iterator);
    $values = iterator_to_array($values);
    print_r($values);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa `yield`, está criando uma [*generator function*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php), e [segundo a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php#language.generators.object), o retorno dela sempre é um objeto do tipo [`Generator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php). Podemos ver isso mudando um pouco seu código:

```
function getValues(&$iterator){
    while($iterator < 1) {
        $iterator++;
        yield ['valor1', 'valor2'];
    }
}

$iterator = 0;

echo "primeira chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values) {
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}

echo "\nsegunda chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values) {
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}

echo "\nterceira chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values) {
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}
```

Em vez de um *loop*, eu chamei `getValues` várias vezes para vermos o que acontece a cada iteração. A saída é:

```
primeira chamada
object(Generator)#8 (0) {
}
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => valor1
            [1] => valor2
        )

)

segunda chamada
object(Generator)#10 (0) {
}
Array
(
)

terceira chamada
object(Generator)#8 (0) {
}
Array
(
)
```

Ou seja, na primeira chamada ele retorna o array e da segunda em diante, não tem mais nenhum valor, pois ele já se encerrou.

Mas `getValues` sempre retorna o objeto `Generator`, e este sempre é avaliado como `true`. Por isso que o seu *loop* nunca termina.

---

O ideal é iterar com um `foreach` mesmo, pois assim ele se encerra automaticamente quando o *generator* terminar.

Mas se quer fazer com `while`, uma forma é verificar se um *generator* já "terminou", usando o [método `valid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.valid.php):

```
function getValues(&$iterator){
    while($iterator < 1) {
        $iterator++;
        yield ['valor1', 'valor2'];
    }
}

$iterator = 0;

echo "primeira chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values->valid()) { // <--- aqui
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}

echo "\nsegunda chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values->valid()) { // <--- aqui
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}

echo "\nterceira chamada\n";
$values = getValues($iterator);
var_dump($values);
if ($values->valid()) { // <--- aqui
    print_r(iterator_to_array($values));
} else {
    echo "generator terminou";
}
```

Agora ele não entra mais no `if` a partir da segunda iteração, pois não há mais valores no *generator*. A saída é:

```
primeira chamada
object(Generator)#8 (0) {
}
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => valor1
            [1] => valor2
        )

)

segunda chamada
object(Generator)#10 (0) {
}
generator terminou
terceira chamada
object(Generator)#8 (0) {
}
generator terminou
```

---

Então no seu caso você poderia usar um *loop* infinito e só interrompê-lo quando o *generator* terminar (usando `valid` para saber se terminou):

```
while(1) {
    $values = getValues($iterator);
    if (! $values->valid()) break; // generator terminou, interrompe o while
    var_dump($iterator);
    $values = iterator_to_array($values);
    print_r($values);
}
```

Ou fazer tudo de uma vez na condição do `while`:

```
while(($values = getValues($iterator))->valid()) {
    var_dump($iterator);
    $values = iterator_to_array($values);
    print_r($values);
}
```

Se bem que não precisa ficar chamando `getValues` o tempo todo:

```
$gen = getValues($iterator);
while ($gen->valid()) {
    $values = $gen->current(); // pega o valor atual
    var_dump($iterator);
    print_r($values);
    $gen->next(); // avança para o próximo
}
```

Mas eu ainda prefiro usar o `foreach` mesmo:

```
foreach (getValues($iterator) as $values) {
    var_dump($iterator);
    print_r($values);
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada!